# Spinnaker-Halyard - Error Fetching Application

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, devops, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I was finally able make spinnaker up. but I am not able to access Projects, Applications. Getting following error. Also I want to know how to change the configuration from localhost to ip address in which file. so I can make it available for users. once this is done I can plan to enable authentication mechanism.

[image]

[image: vo]

Answer (score 2):

Please use one of the below mentioned method based on Service Type

**If using LoadBalancer Service Type for Gate/Deck**

```
hal config security ui edit --override-base-url "http://$Deck_LoadBalancer_IP:9000" 
hal config security api edit --override-base-url "http://$Gate_LoadBalancer_IP:8084"
```

Please try to access in browser using "http://$Deck_LoadBalancer_IP:9000"( Please Use Port number while accessing.)

**If using NodePort Service Type for Gate/Deck**

```
hal config security ui edit --override-base-url "http://$SPIN_HOST:DeckNodePortIP" 
hal config security api edit --override-base-url "http://$SPIN_HOST:GateNodePortIP"
```

**After updation deploy and verify(Make sure all pods-container is up and running)**

```
hal deploy apply
```

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same issue, have set up Spinnaker on Kubernetes Cluster(Kubeadm cluster installed on EC2 instances), with s3 for storage(required permissions given to IAM ) and halyard on debian. When I had a check on browser logs I was able to see 
GET http://localhost:8084 though I have used below commands;

hal config security ui edit --override-base-url "http://:32323"
hal config security api edit --override-base-url "http://:32324"
[browser logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0L5T.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is issue likely because the Spin-gate service is not accessible from your browser. In order to access the Spinnaker UI from the browser, you should make sure that both spin-gate (API) and spin-deck (UI) services are accessible. By default, the spin-gate (API) URL is set to `http://localhost:8084` and the spin-deck URL is set to `http://localhost:9000`. So when you are trying to access the Spinnaker UI using the IP address the Spinnaker UI is trying to connect to the Spin-gate (API) on the URL `http://localhost:8084` which might be causing this issue.

So you should update the Spinnaker gate and Spinnaker deck URLs in the halyard configurations. You can do this either from CLI or by editing the ~/.hal/config file.

From the command line:

- `hal config security ui edit --override-base-url "http://spin-ui-ip"`
- `hal config security api edit --override-base-url "http://spin-api-ip"`

Or by editing the following values in your ~/.hal/config file:

```
currentDeployment: default
deploymentConfigurations:
- name: default
  ...
  ...
  ...
  security:
    apiSecurity:
      ssl:
        enabled: false
      overrideBaseUrl: http://spin-api-ip
    uiSecurity:
      ssl:
        enabled: false
      overrideBaseUrl: http://spin-ui-ip
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, have added the overrideurl's

```
 security:
apiSecurity:
  ssl:
    enabled: false
  overrideBaseUrl: http://52.31.223.77:32324
uiSecurity:
  ssl:
    enabled: false
  overrideBaseUrl: http://52.31.223.77:32323
```

Still the issue exists.